# 2nd monitor not displaying

Tags: display, dual-boot, monitors, odin

I'm fairly new to Linux and have Odin 6 dual booted alongside windows 10 with 2 monitors. Below is information on my 2 monitors.

1. Acer [WORKS] - 1920*1080, 60HZ, connected through Display Port
2. LG [DOESNT WORK ]- 2560*1440, 144HZ, NVIDIA G-Sync, HDR, connected through Display Port

Whenever I start up Odin the process begins showing on monitor 2, but then the screen goes black and I have to turn it off to get it to display on monitor 1. Once its displayed on monitor 1 I can turn monitor 2 back on, but it still has a black screen. It also causes micro stuttering when the 2nd monitor is on. It still detects the monitor as I can see it in the settings and I can drag applications into it, I just can't see them.

---

### What I've Tried

1. Changing the refresh rate in the settings of monitor 2
2. Setting monitor 2 as the default monitor
3. Power cycling my monitor
4. Unplugging/Re-plugging the display port
5. Unplugging monitor 1

So far none of these work so if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My monitors worked after I switched monitor 2 from a connection with a display port to an HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

Me too, happened after a reset, i found by going to advanced options before booting elementary os, by choosing a different version, both displays work